# Special access control for property in CLI/C# class

Tags: c++, properties, command-line-interface

I'm trying to force the code that uses my class to always get one of it's properties directly -- never save it and use it separately.  For example, I want the following to be uncompilable.

```
int x = myObj->prop1;
int y = x + 1;
```

I want to force them to get the value like this:

```
int y = myObj->prop1 + 1;
```

I'm guessing it's not possible, but I figure if it is then someone here will know.

If you want to know why, it's complicated but has to do with forcing the code to use my class in a way that is forward-compatible with a future iteration of the class.

Comment: @onemach C# does not have `->` for objects so it can't be C#

Comment: Could you possibly have the data returned as a const? You could then limit which routines and\or operators could be applied on the object by declaring particular members functions\overloads to be constant or not - this is rather messy though, I must admit. I know you can do this in C++, I'm not sure what language you're working in.

Comment: You cannot alter the behavior of the *int* type.

Comment: @Hans I didn't want to, I wanted to force the user to use my object's property a certain way, the type of the property is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return some kind of non-copyable proxy instead of an instance of the stored variable. But please consider that for value types, the returned instance is a completely indepent copy of the backing field of your property so the client of your library has no possibility to do 'any harm'... Hm, maybe you should explain your intent in more detail...

Comment: After posting my own answer, I realize that it is pretty much what you're saying here, so you'll get the bump.  I'll leave my answer just in case someone needs it more barney-style.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to return a reference to an object but not allow the user to store the reference -- the "int" example was a bad one to illustrate this (sorry).  When you return a reference, all bets are off, so what I was trying to do isn't possible specifically.

However, I realize now that if you want to do this, you need your property to NOT be a reference.  As long as you can represent your property with an unmanaged object, this is possible.

For example, my "Foo" class has a "Point" reference that has X and Y values.

I can add a property to Foo that returns a struct with the X and Y values, not the reference to the object itself.

Then an external object can see the value of the Point object but not mess with the object itself.

Another way is to make the "Point" members/methods mostly internal so when Foo returns it as a property, an external assembly can't really do much but read the X Y values.

Thanks for the attention everyone!